# html textarea ignoring javascript when set to runat="server" in ASP

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, textarea, runatserver

I'm quite new to html and asp.

The problem is that i've defined a textarea that resizes depending on the content it has (using javascript functions).

It works like a charm till i set that textarea to runat="server". Then the resizing doesn't work anymore.

Why is this?
How can i fix it?

Comment: Do you have any markup that you can post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to changed id of controls have runat="server", you can user [ClientIDMode="static"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you are using framework 4 or above or use the ClientID instead of id of control.

**Using [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" ></textarea>
```

**Using [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2" runat="server" ></textarea>
```

*In javascript*

```
  TextArea1 = document.getElementById("<%= TextArea1.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thought visual studio managed this somehow but i see it doesn't.

Comment: Anyway the non-static ids are perfect to add controls dynamically. I'll have in mind the second option you mentioned when adding javascript to those controls to retrieve the correct html object.